# Zend Framework application without virtual hosts

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, iis

Is it possible to configure web server on Windows (Apache or IIS) without setting up virtual hosts so Zend Framework application could be accessed with link like http://example.com/myapp rather than http://example.com/myapp/public?

Comment: Have a look at similar questions at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151246/install-zend-framework-without-apache-virtual-hosts or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274839/zend-app-on-host-without-mod-rewrite-and-no-virtual-hosts

Comment: I did but there's no answer to my question. I don't want the link to include 'public'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]
```

and put this in application.ini

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/myapp/"
```

Comment: Great! This is what I needed. It works perfectly on Apache and should be easy enough to translate .htaccess rules to IIS web.config Thanks!

Comment: @Zebooka why did you use `?${QUERY_STRING}` and `[QSA]`? I thought `[QSA]` appends the query string already :)

Comment: @SamuelHerzog in mine case it strangely didn't for GET parameters :)

Comment: @Zebooka how to use this settings in ZF2 application?

Comment: Where is the location of application.ini ? Shall I create a new file ? Where to put it ?

Comment: how to do the same in zf2?

Answer (score 1):

Put `.htaccess` file wit the following content to your `myapp` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I get 404 error because 'myapp' is recognized as controller while it should default to 'index'

Comment: I've a site where it works fine. I put this `.htaccess` to root directory (`../public`) and it has also another `.htaccess` in public directory that shipped with ZF.

Comment: if it does not work, you can check out this site: http://blog.tasuki.org/htaccess-document-root-and-zend-framework/

Comment: Thanks for the link but it doesn't help in this case. These rules probably work ok if your application is hosted on domain level (http://example.com/) but the problems begin when it's in a folder (http://example.com/myapp)

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file and place it into root direectory with following content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1
```

And add below line to your application/configs/applicaton.ini file

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/myapp/"
```

There will be no error I will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in zend documentation here https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html#using-the-built-in-php-cli-server, You can use the built-in CLI server using command

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php
```

to run this just open command prompt and type above command like this

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t {path_of_project's_public_folder} {path_of_project's_public_folder_upto_idex.php_file}
```

then hit enter and now you can open to your project like this http://localhost:8080/. Your application is running on 8080 port you can change it to something else like 8000 or 5050.

I hope it will help someone.