# Zend frame work url problem?

Tags: php, zend-framework, url

i am getting url is `http://localhost:8888/qmc/public/index.php/get-quote`

but i want to `http://localhost:8888/get-quote`..
using zend..

Comment: There are a lot of similar question here, please check out them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992237/zend-framework-application-without-virtual-hosts/4992373 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274839/zend-app-on-host-without-mod-rewrite-and-no-virtual-hosts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151246/install-zend-framework-without-apache-virtual-hosts

Comment: Could you please stop indenting *all* your text? Indented text is for code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure your virtualhost and .htaccess file. 
Read this [post](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter) for details.